# ATmega328p and USB conection to PC

Tags: avr, atmega

For my project I need to be able to program the eeprom of an Atmega 328p via an USB to PC. I tried to incorporate an USBasp programmer (http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) in my circuit but I was unsuccessful. The PC does not recognise the programmer so I am unable to install the drivers. 
So my question is: does anybody know how can I update the Atmega 328p eeprom via USB.
Is there any basic communication I could use?

I know there are boot loaders, but my programming skills are not adequate to make my own and I can not find an appropriate one.

My code for the Atmega 328 is written in Atmel studio 6.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: You might consider asking this on [EEng](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I moved the question.